# Where do baby ducklings come from?

Tags: placid-plastic-duck-simulator

In Placid Plastic Duck Simulator, sometimes a set of three baby ducklings will appear in the pool. What causes the baby ducklings to appear? Is there a specific type of duck required to make them spawn?

[image: three baby ducks]
<sub>Screenshot from [RTGame - Placid Plastic Duck Simulator: A Dramatic Masterpiece (4:42)](https://youtu.be/Q3N-fVqUEms?t=282)</sub>

Comment: When a daddy duck and a mommy duck love ea... owh, wrong site...